# Remove javadoc sonar check from specific class

Tags: java, javadoc, sonarqube

How to go about disabling javadoc sonar check on a specific class? (We don't want to clutter up some short boiler-plate method with unusefull javadoc).

Is there a more specific key than `@SuppressWarnings("all")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Switch Off Violations plugin: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

This feature will be available as a core feature in SonarQube 4.0.

You can take a look at https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3644